# Removing last line in a file iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, file-io

How can I remove last line in a file in iOS.

Below is the code that let's me go to the end of file but then I don't know how to remove that last line.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.daa", documentsDirectory, MFILE_NAME];

NSFileHandle *aFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:file]; 
//setting aFileHandle to write at the end of the file
[aFileHandle truncateFileAtOffset:[aFileHandle seekToEndOfFile]];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some documentation reading this is what I ended up with:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt", documentsDirectory, @"file_name"];

    NSData *orgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

    //Because there is only one char on my last line I make a range from 0 to length of data - 1 byte.
    NSRange range = {0, [orgData length]-1};

    NSData* shortData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file] subdataWithRange:range];

    [shortData writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
```

If you know a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that this can be your solution:

```
NSFileHandle *file;
file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:[self filePath]];

if (file == nil)
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file");

//get the last character count
long long lastChar = [file seekToEndOfFile];
lastChar--;
lastChar--;

//from where do you want to remove 
NSLog (@"Offset = %llu", lastChar);
//Move to position
[file seekToFileOffset: lastChar];

//write an empty string
[file writeData:[@" " dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[file closeFile];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly okay, depending on the file.

Removing one character doesn't address thing like a trailing carriage return, so this may not actually work in practice. A better (more general) solution would be to load the file, and step backwards from the last character until you find the beginning of the last line (i.e. everything between the next-to-last carriage return and the final one), and then rewrite the file without the final line.